# How to delete the parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have used questions method to take the params from view, it takes the params and sends the mail, but I am redirecting to questions again, due to that it goes in loop, now I want to delete the params after delivering the mail. tell me the method to delete the params so I can avoid loop.
Thanks.

```
def questions
    if params[:email] 
        @recipient = params[:email]
        @subject = "Question form #{params[:name]}"
        @body = params[:question]
        OrderNotifier.question(@recipient, @subject, @body).deliver

        redirect_to "/questions"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a key/value pair from a Hash using `Hash#delete`:

```
params.delete :email
```

You could do this before the redirect.